# Can't get Django Template Inheritance to work

Tags: python, html, django, templates

This seems so simple and yet it refuses to work...

I have my base.html file:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    {% block title %}
    Simple Skeleton
    {% endblock title %}
  </title>
```

and my home.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<% block title %>
Resource List
<% endblock %>
```

(they are both a bit longer but I feel this is all that is necessary)

The home.html completely fails to overwrite the sections within the code blocks - the page title remains "Simple Skeleton" and not "Resource List" despite me accessing the home.html file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is `{% ... %}`, not `<% ... %>`.

Answer (score 2):

*Django template tags* are written between `{% … %}`, not <s>`<% … %>`</s>, so `{% block title %}`, not <s>`<% block title %>`</s>:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Resource List
{% endblock %}
```

By not using the proper template tag, Django will not render this content: it is content outside a block, so it will not have an effect on the inherited template.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo error in `home.html`. Use `{% %}` for template tags instead of <s>`<% %>`</s>.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} 
    Resource List
{% endblock %}
```